# Azure WorkerRole Dynamic MaxConcurrentCalls

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azureservicebus

I am creating a Worker Role using Windows Azure and have the following code:

```
OnMessageOptions options = new OnMessageOptions() { MaxConcurrentCalls = 10 };
...
Client.OnMessage((receivedMessage) =>
{
   ...
}, options);
```

**Is it possible to update the `MaxConcurrentCalls` after the the message pump has started?**

I would like to control this in the Azure Configuration Settings instead of hard-coding it. As I change the Configuration, it should be reflected upon in the Worker Role.

I know that the WorkerRole checks for configuration changes, how do I **modify** `MaxConcurrentCalls` during that check?

(If not, that would be a greatly desired feature.)

Answer (score 0):

Any update to CloudConfig file would trigger restart of the worker role. I believe all you need to do is pick up maxconcurrent connection setting from cloud config file using:

```
CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("MaxConcurrentConnection")
```

Comment: The first part of your answer is not correct. Changing the cloud configuration settings won't automatically trigger a role recycle. That would be bad if it did that. It is up to you, as the developer, to request a recycle by detecting a change in the configuration setting. You can subscribe to the role's [Changing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.changing.aspx) and [Changed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.changed.aspx) events during startup to decide when to restart.